# Syslog forwarding to Rsyslog

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, powerpc

I was wondering if anyone was familiar with the process of forwarding all log files from a PPC Gnu/Linux using syslog (installing rsyslog is not an option) to a x86_64 GNU/Linux running Rsyslog.

I will need to keep the logs of both systems separate and of course rotate logs out periodically.I figured that modifying the syslog.conf file by adding the following line at the end of it should make it work, but it does not. Any other steps I need to take?

```
*.* @ip-address
```

Thank you

Comment: You need a space between `*.*` and `@ip-address`.  Is this a typo here?

Comment: Yes that is a typo on my post, I will correct it right now

Comment: Just checked UDP 514 on the rsyslog host and it is in fact open. How do I try switching to TCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The receiving rsyslog server needs to be configured too. Depending on the version you can add to the start of `/etc/rsyslog.conf` (look for these lines commented out):

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

Comment: I think this actually did it. Any way I could send a message to check if it worked? I do see some logs being updated

Comment: You might have the `logger` command, eg `logger -p user.err 'hello there'`.